# Magento 2 - Extend table rates shipping methods

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, table-rates

I've configured table rates with my custom rates from backend and it works fine. But I need to add two custom rules:

- when a single product weight is higher than 25 kg the shipping cost increase by 8€.
- If the product weight is higher than 50 kg the shipping costs have an increase of 8€ plus 0.26€ for each kg over the 50th kg (so for instance if the product weight is 51 kg the shipping costs have an increase of 8,26€, while if the product weight is 52 kg the shipping costs have an increase of 8,52€).

So I would like to extend the custom workflow of table rates calculation and add these rules. How I could do it?